# why some locally constant sheaves aren't constant?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Many times you have to show that a certain sheaf, maybe obtained as gluing of other sheaves, is not constant ; there are methods or tricks immediate or generally to do this?
What is special about a constant sheaf that other sheaves (e.g. those locally constant ) don't have ?

in particular cases :

- if $X$ is not connected and disjoint union of two open not empty subset $U, V$ and if i take the sheaves constant on $U$ and $V$ and glue them (for example i can take the zero sheaf on $U$ and the constant sheaf with stalk $K$ on $V$); why I don't get a constant sheaf?
- if $X = \mathbb{R}\cup S^{1}$, why the sheaf locally constant that I get as gluing of the two constant sheaves $\mathbb{R}_{\mathbb{R}}$ and $\mathbb{R}_{\mathbb{S^{1}}}$ is not constant ?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606952/locally-constant-sheaf-but-not-constant

Comment: I already read the question that you linked me; But i would have more details in this two example and i would understand in general how approach this problem.

Comment: But isn't it answered there? If the underlying space is the circle $S^1$ and the sheaf consists of sections of the map $z\mapsto z^2$, then the sheaf locally assigns to a set $U$ the 2-element group $\{\pm \sqrt{z}\}$ (considered as two functions on $U$). But the square root can not be extended to a global function.

Comment: of course! i understood this example perfectly . But I don't know how to carry these reasoning in my two problems ; for example, the first problem that I have written seems to need a very different approach respect to the example you're talking about.