# Constant sheaf vs locally constant sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I'm getting very confused distinguishing the difference between a locally constant sheaf and a constant sheaf.

$\textbf{Constant sheaf}$: Let M be a vector space.  The constant sheaf over $X$ is given by
$$\underline{M}(U) = \{s: U \to M | s\text{ constant on connected components}\}$$
where $U\subset X$ open, with restriction given by restriction of functions gives the constant sheaf with value M.

$\textbf{Locally constant sheaf}$: A sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ such that there is an open cover ${U_{\alpha}}$ of X with $\mathcal{F}|_{U_{\alpha}}$ is a constant sheaf.

I know that a constant sheaf is a locally constant sheaf but I don't see why a locally constant sheaf isn't a constant sheaf.

Take the example that you have $X = U_1 \sqcup U_2$, the disjoint union of two connected open sets, and take two different constant sheaves defined on each connected piece. This is supposedly locally a constant sheaf but not a constant sheaf. But by definition of the constant sheaf, we have that this sheaf is constant on connected components as it is constant on $U_1$ and constant on $U_2$, no? But this is the same logic I would use for locally constant sheaf?

Also, if anyone could shed some light on how to view the covering map over the circle, $z \to z^2$, as a sheaf that would be great. How is this a locally constant sheaf? It's a map, not a sheaf?

I've seen this post, but I think what I want is it explained in more detail
[Locally constant sheaf but not constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606952/locally-constant-sheaf-but-not-constant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be a space endowed with a discrete topology, and $X$ a topological space, the constant sheaf defined by $A$ is the sheaf such that for every open subset $U$ of $X$, $M(U)$ is the space of continuous maps $U\rightarrow A$.

Let $X=\{x_1,x_2\}$, $U_1=\{x_1\},U_2=\{x_2\}$ are open subset Let $A_1=\{a\}, A_2=\{a,b\}$, defined $M(U_i)$ is the space of continuous map $U_i\rightarrow A_i$ and $M(X)$ is the space of continuous maps $X\rightarrow \{a,b\}$
$M$  is a sheaf if $s_i:U_i\rightarrow A_i$, we can extend $s_i$ to $X$ by setting $s(x_i)=s_i(x_i)$, remark that $s$ may not be constant but continuous since $X$ is not connected.

$M$ is locally constant since it is constant on $U_i$, but $M$ is not constant.

Comment: Does that mean that on a disconnected set, we can never have a constant sheaf (as the gluing condition wouldn't be satisfied) but we can have a locally constant sheaf?

Comment: If $X$ is any topological set, take $A$ a non empty set and define $M(U)=A$ if $U$ is an open subset, the restriction maps is the identity define a constant sheaf on $X$

Comment: Take $X=U_1 \sqcup U_2$. By definition, $M(U_1)=\mathbb{Z}$, $M(U_2)=\mathbb{Z}$ and $M(X)=\mathbb{Z}$ as $X$ is also clearly open. Take $s_i \in M(U_i)$ such that $s_i=i$, so $s_1=1$ and $s_2=2$. I'm assuming the restriction maps to the empty set is just the trivial map, in which case, $s_1|_{U_1 \cap U_2} = s_2|_{U_1 \cap U_2}$, as $U_1 \cap U_2 = \emptyset$. But this doesn't glue to a section of $s \in M(X)$ that is constant, as we would require $s =k$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Constant sheaf means that $M(U)=A$ and the restrictions functions are the identity, it does not means that the sections are constant

Comment: I think this is the part I'm missing, any chance you could explain it in a bit more detail? I'm not seeing where that example I just gave is going wrong, am I incorrectly using the definitions?

Comment: If $M(U)=\mathbb{Z}$, a section $s \in M(U)$ has to be constant $s=k$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, no?

Comment: It is constant if $U$ is connected

Comment: @TsemoAristide Sorry but your definition of constant sheaf is wrong, you only define the constant presheaf. The definition in the OP is the good one. Moreover I don't understand how $M$ is a sheaf. You said $M(X)$ is the set of continuous maps $X\to\{a,b\}$. How do you restrict the constant map with value $b$ on $U_1$ if $M(U_1)$ is the space of continuous map $U_1\to\{a\}$ ?